# Video not playing in HTML on Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: html

I want to embed a video in an HTML file.I am using the following code. This video is working when i open it on the desktop but its not playing when i upload it on the server. I tried it for chrome and Mozilla but it's not working. Also no errors are showing in the console.
        Please help me find out where I am going wrong.

```
<video controls autoplay width="800" height="450">
          <source src="cfr.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```

Comment: check the browser console, do you get any errors? 404?

Comment: no errors are getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have given the link to the video as follows

This will work when your site is working in local server.

When you upload it to the server give the proper path to the video file

suppose the video is in uploads folder then the link would look like this

Answer (score 0):

If you're linking to something off your site, then you must use the absolute path because there is no relative path to use.
If you link to a page that is in another folder (directory) on your site,

page.html is located in the current directory.

page.html is located in a folder (directory) called tips. The "tips" folder is located in the current directory.

page.html is located in a folder called other that is located in a folder called tips that is located in the current directory.

../   represents one level up to the browser